# Why does Debian's PHP sessionclean script touch all open files first?

Tags: php, debian

I'm studying `/usr/lib/php/sessionclean` at the moment. There is one thing I don't fully understand. What is the purpose of touching all opened session files before cleaning up? I understand that this prevents the deletion of expired sessions that are currently open but have not yet been written to. But isn't this still a race condition? What if a PHP process opens an expired session file between the touch and the delete commands?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Session files that are older than the maximum lifetime, at the time the `find` command evaluates them,  will be deleted.

Files are updated at the latest when the PHP script finishes execution. However, perhaps it is not really fair to kill a session for being idle while it is executing.  Thus, the `touch` updates the modify time on session files which have a php process currently executing.

Yes, there is a race condition of a php process starting after the `touch`, resuming a too old session, and getting deleted because it did not finish before the `find` did garbage collection. The session already existed for its full lifetime, probably several minutes. Missing an extension in a fraction of a second window isn't a big deal.

---

The alternative, PHP's built in implementation, has a 1% or so chance of running garbage collection on execution. For low volume sites, it might not trigger reliably.

Plus, the external script allows locking down the security on the session directory, which is why Debian maintainers did it that way.